# How to remove Entitlements.plist from Custom Entitlements setting in xcode

Tags: ios

I’m seeing this error message when uploading to Testflight:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'applinks:***.***.*/Wallet/open/*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/V-Wallet.app/V-Wallet' is not supported."

How can I remove  Entitlements.plist from Custom Entitlements setting in Xcode?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

@Karen shah, I believe you are trying to build an IPA file.

Just need to clean it (command + shift +k) and delete all precompiled frameworks  and then build again.

Comment: perhaps try it with a new project, build the ipa file. If it works add the precompiled frameworks sequentally, and build it again? Since we don't have your project file, it's hard to tell what's the root cause